# ApplicationRoleManager is null ASP.NET

Tags: c#

Im trying to get all aplication Roles to show it in View
But isnt works
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBCoU.png)

Comment: From the image no one can guess the answer. Please check the rules. Images are not allowed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I just added

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<AppRoleManager>(AppRoleManager.Create);
```

in Startup.cs into

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
```